# while creating ORC file table in hive Ubuntu its getting failed.FAILED: Error in semantic analysis: Unrecognized file format in STORED AS clause: orc

Tags: hive, hiveql, ubuntu-16.04

```
hive> create table orc_table (name string,img_loc string) stored as orc tblproperties("orc.compress"="none");

FAILED: Error in semantic analysis: Unrecognized file format in STORED AS clause: orc


hive> create table orc_table (name string,img_loc string) stored as orcfile tblproperties("orc.compress"="none");

FAILED: Error in semantic analysis: Unrecognized file format in STORED AS clause: orcfile


hive> create table orc_table(name string,img_loc string) stored as orcfile;

FAILED: Error in semantic analysis: Unrecognized file format in STORED AS clause: orcfile



hive> create table orc_table(name string,img_loc string) stored as orc;    
FAILED: Error in semantic analysis: Unrecognized file format in STORED AS clause: orc
```

Answer (score 0):

here you Load non ORC file thats why this error occur. So best Solution is first make a table load a data and insert this tables into orc table

```
CREATE TABLE data(value1 string, value2 string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|';
```

here terminated by b "|" Because I am using PSV file you can set as per your file formate.

```
LOAD DATA INPATH '/user/hive/data.psv' INTO TABLE data;

create data2 stored as ORC tblproperties ("orc.compress" = "SNAPPY");

insert into data2 select * from data;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the your HIVE version is greater then 0.11. ORC is introduced in 0.11 version

```
ORC         -- (Note: Available in Hive 0.11.0 and later)
```

How to check hive version

```
$ hive --version
Hive 0.14.0.2.2.4.8-40
```

- [HIVE-3874: Create a new Optimized Row Columnar file format for Hive.](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-3874) - this is the implementation ticket.
- [Hive Create Table syntax](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-Create/Drop/TruncateTable) - check `file_format` to know minimum requirement for each storage type.
- [ORC Files](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+ORC) - Information about ORC files.